# What is the derivative of the differential operator itself with respect to function-space valued inputs?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

$\partial_t[x(t)]$ is a function, $\partial_t,$ whose input is real-valued functions, just as $x(t)$ is a function of real-valued numbers.

Well, I'd like to understand the implications of calculus with respect to function-space valued inputs of the standard differential operator.

What is the derivative of the differential operator mapping with respect to the input of elements of a Banach space, $x \in X$? Let's denote the derivative with respect to the standard differential operator's input as $\partial_x$ and its (whatever) derivative as $\partial'_t$

I would expect this to follow a few properties,

$\partial_x[x] = 1,$

$\partial_x[\partial_t\partial_t[x]] = (\partial' \partial_t + \partial_t\partial'_t)[x]$ (product rule)

$\partial_x[\partial^2_t] = 2\partial'_t\partial_t[x]$ (power rule).

Does this framework make sense? And if so, what is $\partial'_t$ with respect to $t$?

Comment: $x(t)$ **is not a function!**

Comment: Yes it is? The differential operator is defined over infinitely many function spaces.

Comment: $x$ is a function. $x(t)$ is the function $x$, evaluated at the input $t$.

Comment: The domain is a space of functions of a variable, $x$ such as for instance $C^1_{[a,b]}$ defined over evaluations of $[a,b].$ $x$ is not a function unless it's a function *of something* and there's nothing wrong with that something being a real variable. I'm not seeing any conflict here, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functional derivative of the derivative operator $D$ at the function $f$ is $g \mapsto \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{D[f+\varepsilon g]-D[f]}{\varepsilon}=g \mapsto \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} D[g]=g \mapsto D[g]$. So $D$ is its own functional derivative. This always happens with an operator that is already linear.

I don't really understand what you're asking in the rest of your question, maybe you can clarify.

Comment: I'm asking that, if we have a function whose input is other functions, what is the derivative of that function with respect to its input? It looks like you may have answered that, but there's at least several different abstractions of the derivative so I don't know for sure. I understand the Frechet derivative of a linear operator is indeed *some* linear operator, but is it always itself?

Comment: @StackQuest The functional derivative of the derivative operator is the derivative operator, that is what I said. There is more to be done with something like the functional derivative of $f \mapsto (D[f])^2$, which is what you seem to be actually asking about in your second case. Unless you are asking about the derivative of $f \mapsto D[D[f]]$, in which case that is again itself since that is linear as well.

Comment: @StackQuest And yes the Frechet derivative of a linear operator is always itself. This follows from the above calculation, just replace $D$ by whatever linear operator you like.

Comment: Okay, thank you for answering!

Comment: What about the derivative with respect to the operator, but applied to $x$ itself? Is that $=1$?

Comment: @StackQuest I don't understand the question. Do you mean the Frechet derivative of $D$ evaluated at $f(x)=x$? That would be $g \mapsto g$. Keep in mind here that the Frechet derivative views derivatives as linear maps, so the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}[x]=1$ is really telling you that the derivative is the mapping $x \mapsto 1 \cdot x = x$ (i.e. the approximate change in the function for a given displacement is equal to the displacement).